# What (Fedora) Linux tool can I use to view my desktop on the same network from my laptop?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, fedora, fedora-12, workspace

What I want is for my desktop to appear as a window from my laptop. Both are running on Fedora 12. Better if my desktop can appear as the other workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the remote login feature of X and export the display of the desktop to your laptop, but that'd mean the applications from the desktop would have their own windows in the laptop.

If you want to keep them separate, I'd recommend using VNC for remote desktop access. In that way, all the "screen" of the desktop will be "painted" withing the same app in the laptop, the vnc viewer of your choice.

Hope this helps

Comment: Currently installing VNC now using TigerVNC for the client.

Comment: `yum install vnc-server vnc' on both machines did the trick. Easy peasy.