# Better quality alternative to FreeNX?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, rdesktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What (Fedora) Linux tool can I use to view my desktop on the same network from my laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/88988/what-fedora-linux-tool-can-i-use-to-view-my-desktop-on-the-same-network-from-my)

I've been trying FreeNX on openSuse for a few hours and found that it's extremely buggy and poorly documented. I've never gotten it to work.

Could you suggest a better alternative? For those who don't know, FreeNX is used to get a remote desktop session on a linux machine.

Comment: Several dupes: http://superuser.com/questions/88988/what-fedora-linux-tool-can-i-use-to-view-my-desktop-on-the-same-network-from-my, http://superuser.com/questions/88988/what-fedora-linux-tool-can-i-use-to-view-my-desktop-on-the-same-network-from-my, http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop+linux

Comment: FreeNX is based off NoMachine.  Have you tried using the original? http://www.nomachine.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the different VNC clients and servers out there : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing